# How can I add JS code that dynamically wrap any function invocation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-framework, serverside-javascript, ecmascript-5

I had like to wrap any JavaScript invocation at runtime,
e.g. I had like to write to a log that an invocation of Func has been occurred.

This wrapping must work for any function even those function that has been added using eval or prototyping.

Comment: You can't do this without writing it in C++ as a nodejs extension

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding console.log to every function automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033836/adding-console-log-to-every-function-automatically)

Comment: @Raynos , what about the client-side? I guess it's the same answer since it's the same v8?

Comment: @MrOhad there is nothing you can hook into. You can edit global function but you can't do the same with local functions. You can write a firefox/chrome extension to hook into this for you ;)

Comment: @Raynos if I could analyzed (statically) the code first I guess that would be possible, what do you think?

Comment: @MrOhad By all means you can use a compiler on your js source to compile it to source that is logged. You can also plug a mod into the nodejs or V8 to allow hooking into function calls. Look at [node-proxy](https://github.com/isaacs/node-proxy)

Comment: @Raynos, please add it as an answer and I will accept it..

Comment: @MrOhad node proxy only works with node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is [node-proxy](https://github.com/isaacs/node-proxy)

You can't do this using native JS. This will only work for `node.js`. It can probably be adjusted to work for any js running on V8.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to call your functions with the `call` method, you could do something like this:

```
oldCall = Function.prototype.call;
Function.prototype.call = function(){
 // do some logging here
 oldCall.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid it's impossible in pure JavaScript.