# How do I call a javascript function given a mapping of variables to values?

Tags: javascript

Say I have this function:

```
function doSomething(uno, dos, tres) {
    // do something
}
```

and this object:

```
{
    dos: 'foo',
    tres: 'bar',
    uno: 'baz'
}
```

How do I call `doSomething` given this mapping? I tried using `apply`, but it seems that `apply` must take a list instead of an object.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support named arguments, so you'll have to convert them into an array of positional arguments. Related: [Named parameters in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796093/named-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: What if the only relationship between the object and the function parameters is captured in the variable names?

Comment: You'd do `doSomething.apply(this, names.map(function(name) {return obj[name];}))`

Answer (score 3):

You can refer each property in the object as given above using `.` as given below.

```
doSomething(obj.uno, obj.dos, obj.tres)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can only be used to apply an *array-like* object<sup>1</sup> to a function call. There is no equivalent to Pythons "keyword argument expansion" and this must be done manually:

```
var opts = {
    dos: 'foo',
    tres: 'bar',
    uno: 'baz'
}
doSomething(opts.uno, opts.dos, opts.tres)
```

If we started with an *array-like* object:

```
var arr = ['baz', 'foo', 'bar']
doSomething.apply(window, arr)
```

Or putting the two together (so that the composition of to a parameter sequence can be handled earlier):

```
var arr = [opts.uno, opts.dos, opts.tres]
doSomething.apply(window, arr)
```

While it *may* be possible (with non-obfuscated code) to use [`Function.toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.2)<sup>2</sup> to extract the parameter names, do some parsing, and then write some code to "apply" a general object (or construct an array that is then applied), this is not supported directly by the ECMAScript specification.

---

<sup>1</sup> An *array-like* object is one that has a `length` and properties named `0..length-1`. (Old versions of FF had a bug, but that has been fixed for a long time.)

<sup>2</sup> The wording of the specification ("An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration..") makes me believe that a conforming ES5 implementation *ought to* produce output usable for this purpose - however, this will likely vary by implementation and I have not explored such usage in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
function doSomething() {
   for (var i = 0, l = arguments.length; i<l; i++) {
      //dosomething
      console.log(arguments[i]);
   }
}

obj=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
doSomething.apply(null, obj);
```

Apply accepts array as second parameter but 
if you insist on using object you can easily convert this object to Array and then use it with apply.

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
   var arr = [];
   for (field in obj) 
      arr.push(field);
   return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Function.prototype.applyNamed = function (g, argArr) {
    var self = this;    
    var argNames = self.toString().match(/function\s+\w*\s*\((.*?)\)/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
    var applyArgs = [];
    for(var i=0; i<argNames.length; i++){        
        applyArgs.push(argArr[argNames[i]]);        
    }
    self.apply(self, applyArgs);
}

function doSomething(uno, dos, tres) {    
    console.log('uno = ' + uno);
    console.log('dos = ' + dos);
    console.log('tres = ' + tres);
}

var namedArgs = {
    dos: 'foo',
    tres: 'bar',
    uno: 'baz'
};

doSomething.applyNamed(this, namedArgs);
```

Should print:

```
uno = baz  
dos = foo  
tres = bar
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AJ7zZ/1/); [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6922026/26224).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to, you actually can call a method using named parameters, but it requires parsing the string representation of the function. Whether or not you *should* use this technique is debatable, but here is how you would do it:

```
function doSomething(uno, dos, tres) {
    // do something
}

var arguments = {
    dos: 'foo',
    tres: 'bar',
    uno: 'baz'
}

function callFunction(fn, namedArguments) {
    var orderedArguments = [];
    var parameterRegExp = /\(([\s\w\$,]*)\)/;

    parameterRegExp.exec(fn.toString())[1].replace(/\s/g, '').split(',').forEach( function(parameterName) {
        orderedArguments.push(namedArguments[parameterName]);
    });

    return fn.apply(this, orderedArguments);
}

callFunction(doSomething, arguments);
```