# Add code to run automatically with each function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

For debugging purposes, I was wondering if there's some way in which I can create a piece of code to run whenever a javascript function is called - like adding something to Function.prototype or Function.constructor etc.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226550/can-i-override-the-javascript-function-object-to-log-all-function-calls

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "decorator-like".

Something as simple as executing

```
var yourFunction = function { // do stuff };
var yourSecondFunction = function { // do stuff };
var myDecorator = function( callback )
{
    // do your stuff
    // ...
    // then execute function
    callback();
};

// usage
myDecorator( yourFunction );
myDecorator( yourSecondFunction );
```

I don't think overwriting the prototype of `Function` is a good idea.