# Javascript log attribute access and function calls

Tags: javascript, prototype, strace

1. Function call: I'm looking to implement an strace like functionality in javascript. That is, I'd like to log all function calls and potentially its arguments, in the order of function calls. **Note** that I'd like to do this in a stand alone js interpreter / headless browser, so browser plugins isn't going to help.
2. Attribute access: Also, is there a way to log every attribute access?

I imagine there may be a way to monkey patch Object functions at the time of attribute access and function invocation? If now, may be do something with javascript engine?

**Update:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23103992/1179293 seems to answer #1, with known limitations. Attribute access (#2) still remains unanswered

Comment: @HectorBarbossa see update regarding use of firebug.

Comment: @MikeC agree, that's the best answer so far on Question 1

Comment: @zonked.zonda You'll never be able to trace every single property lookup but you can wrap objects [in a `Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and track the property accesses of those objects.