# Overriding function keyword in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, overriding

This is rather a strange question but it is a requirement in my project. I want to override the **function** keyword in javaScript. The need is pretty complex but to make it simpler, as soon as I call a function, a `console.log` must be fired. i.e.

```
let myfn = function(x,y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

Now when I call `myfn(5,7)` it should show

> function called

Now, this console must alway show on every function call in my entire project. So I want to centralize this by overriding the default function in JS. Is this possible? If so how?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226550/can-i-override-the-javascript-function-object-to-log-all-function-calls

Comment: Why don't you use Decorators?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I override the Javascript Function object to log all function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226550/can-i-override-the-javascript-function-object-to-log-all-function-calls)

Comment: @user1592129 how do you use decorators?