# Joi: Automatic validation of function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, types, joi

I saw a codebase which was using `joi` library like this:

```js
function f(a, b) {
  // ...
}

f.schema = {
  a: Joi.string().uuid().required(),
  b: Joi.number()
}
```

And then the `f.schema` property wasn't referenced anywhere else. Is there some framework which performs automatic validation of function arguments using the `schema` property? Googling this didn't bring up anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do exactly what you are showing here, since [overloading of function call is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226550/can-i-override-the-javascript-function-object-to-log-all-function-calls) in Javascript, but there is a way to do something pretty similar using [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Here is what I've managed to do. We create a `validated` proxy object, that overrides the `apply` behavior, which corresponds to standard function calls, as well as `apply` and `call` methods.

The proxy checks for the presence of a `schema` property on the function, then validates each argument using the elements of the `schema` array.

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const validated = function(f) {
    return new Proxy(f, {
        apply: function(target, thisArg, arguments) {
            if (target.schema) {
                for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
                    const res = target.schema[i].validate(arguments[i]);
                    if (res.error) {
                        throw res.error;
                    }
                }
            }
            target.apply(thisArg, arguments)
        }
    })
}

const myFunc = validated((a, b) => {
    console.log(a, b)
});

myFunc.schema = [
    Joi.string().required(),
    Joi.number(),
];

myFunc('a', 2);
```