# Javascript function to validate data according to a schema

Tags: javascript, json

I have to write a javascript function which can validate data according to this kind of schema. How should i go about this? Can i use json schema for this. That does'nt work for fucnctions so how should i solve this? Is there any native js way to go about this?

```
const userSchema = {
    name: {
        fn: () => String,
        option: { default: 'Abhi', enum: ['John', 'Rick', 'Dan'] }
    },
    phone: {
        fn: () => Number,
        option: {}
    },
    cart: {
        fn: () => [
            {
                id: {
                    fn: () => String,
                    option: {}
                },
                count: {
                    fn: () => Number,
                    option: {}
                }
            }
        ],
        option: {}
    },
    address: {
        contactName: {
            fn: () => String,
            option: {}
        },
        detailAddress: {
            line1: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            },
            line2: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            },
            line3: {
                fn: () => String,
                option: {}
            }
        },
        pin: {
            fn: () => Number,
            option: {}
        },
        country: {
            fn: () => String,
            option: {}
        }
    }
};
```

```
const user = {
    name: 'Ric',
    phone: 6610592314,
    address: {
        contactName: 'Bitu',
        detailAddress: {
            line1: 'Colony: 2/A',
            line2: 'Q. No.: 3-018',
            line3: 'Near IT store'
        },
        pin: 770017,
        country: 'India'
    },
    cart: [
        {
            id: 'newId',
            count: 2
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Joi](https://joi.dev/) is a good library for this. Flow and TypeScript also work at compile-time, but won't help you with runtime validation. Joi's function validation isn't perfect, but there's a workaround for argument validation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61897947/joi-automatic-validation-of-function-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

I've been working lately on a JS Runtime Scheme Validation Tool, creatively called [Types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codistica/types).

It is still at its early stages (powerful features implementations are expected in the near future), but I think it could fit your needs. Currently it is also able to handle circular schemes.

To install it, do `yarn add @codistica/types` or `npm i @codistica/types`.

Then, here you have an usage example (documentation is still work in progress):

```js
import {Types} from '@codistica/types';

const myFunctionSchema = new Types({
    argA: {type: '!undefined'},
    argB: {type: 'Function'},
    argC: {
        type: 'Object',
        def: {
            propA: {type: 'number', min: 0, max: 20, def: 10},
            propB: {type: 'boolean', def: false},
            propC: {type: ['Function', 'null'], def: null},
            propD: {type: 'Array<number>', def: [0, 1, 2]}
        }
    }
});

function myFunction(argA, argB, argC) {
    ({argA, argB, argC} = myFunctionSchema.validate({
        argA,
        argB,
        argC
    }));

    if (!myFunctionSchema.isValid()) {
        return;
    }
}

export {myFunction};
```

If you would like to give it a try, I would be glad to assist you in any possible way. The above example is really an underestimation. Maybe you could also give us some useful feedback. Please let me know.