# How to detect reason for browser freeze?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in our team we developed a fairly large AngularJS app. A couple of days ago, we have the problem, that the browser/tab freezes on a specific action.

I sadly can't post any code, because it first a closed source project and second I have no clue what part could possibly be responsible for the freeze.

So my general question is: **How can I detect the reason for a browser freeze?**

- Is there any loop that does not exit?
- Are there suddenly too many DOM elements?

I don't even know where to start searching.

If someone needs more information that are not code relevant (I am sorry about that, but I am not allowed to share code here), then please tell me.

Comment: check any backend process may be running..!

Comment: Did you check for console errors and network tab for delayed response or pending status?

Comment: Do this happen for every browser or a specific browser

Comment: @Sajal yes I did. No errors, no pending request. The interessting part is, that the console (Chrome v60 Console) seemingly is not dead.

Comment: At what action?

Comment: You can run a audit to see where the bottleneck is. read more about audits here. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/

Comment: @peter well, to sum it up: make several API calls. This works fine for a random number of time, everytime the same action. And sporadically it causes the browser to freeze.

Comment: @Thusitha I will give it a try.

Comment: Are you dealing with large base64 image files in the api call?

Comment: Check for infinite loops...

Comment: No images. Just Json reponse with a max size of 7KB and a max amount of calls per action of 51.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, good approach. But if a process runs fine for several time, and sporadically breaks, where to start searching?

Comment: Check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289937/how-can-you-debug-javascript-which-hangs-the-browser

Comment: @Thusitha with console.log's before and after I was able to find the villain. Thanks for the idea!