# Not able to load local page written in HTML & JavaScript in Chrome for testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, browser, safari

I am trying to test some JavaScript on my local computer using the Chrome browser but Chrome will not load local resources (web page written in HTML and JavaScript) and ended up with an error message: **Error Code: Result_Code_Hung**.  Does anyone know how to fix this loading problem? Or is there an easy workaround for this?

I tried to open the webpage with Safari, still not able to load the page.

The code is quite simple:

```
  <body>

     <h1> Test Loading</h1>

     <script>
 
         // calculate lcm of two natural numbers using do-while 

        function lcm (a, b){

              if (a>b) {

                 let i=1; 
                 do{
                      let lcNum= (a*i % b ===0) ? a*i: a*b ; 
                  } while (i<=a); 

                  return lcNum; 
              }

              else if (b>a){

                 let i=1; 
                 do{
                        let lcNum = (b*i % a ===0) ? b*i: a*b ; 
                  } while (i<=b); 

                  return lcNum;
              }

         }

        console.log (lcm(4,6)); 

     </script>

  </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you debug JavaScript which hangs the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289937/how-can-you-debug-javascript-which-hangs-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite loop in both `do...while` loops. For example in second one

```js
do{
    let lcNum = (b*i % a ===0) ? b*i: a*b ; 
} while (i<=b);
```

part. `i` is always equal to 1 which and `b` is always equal to 6, that's why `while` loop never breaks. I suggest entering `debugger` into your code

```js
function lcm (a, b){
    debugger
    ...
}
```

and invoke your code from chrome dev tools console like `lcm(4,6)`

Answer (score 0):

Show your code. It might also happen due to some extension, network issues, cache issue. But it is hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: Hi,
I've added the code. Could you please take a look? Thank you.