# Adding console.log to every function automatically - part 2

Tags: javascript, function, logging, hook

Follow up question to the solution posted here:

[Adding console.log to every function automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033836/adding-console-log-to-every-function-automatically)

This works great for getting the name of the function called:

```
function augment(withFn) {
var name, fn;
for (name in window) {
    fn = window[name];
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        window[name] = (function(name, fn) {
            var args = arguments;
            return function() {
                withFn.apply(this, args);
                return fn.apply(this, arguments);

            }
        })(name, fn);
    }
  }
}
```

Can you also list the arguments supplied to the function that was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the code, you can see that fn is being called with arguments, and that is what you want in your function. So just add it to args :

```
withFn.apply(this, Array.from(args).concat([arguments]));
```

Comment: Aha -thanks.  I knew the arguments were there but wasn't concatenating.  Cheers.  For any who are doing this in Max/MSP - Array.from(args) is not available - so use arrayfromargs(args) instead.