# Run a function every time any function in class is called using JS

Tags: javascript

I have simple class like this:

```
module.exports = class MyClass {

    function middleware() {
        console.log('call me before')
    }

    function a() {

    }
    function b() {

    }

    function c() {

    }
}
```

So Idea is, when someone call function a, b, c I want call middleware before execute a, b, c. How can I do it?

So, I can put middleware() to each function, but I want some dynamic way how to do this.

Comment: if anytime you will call function a(), you cant do anything , it will only execute a.

Comment: I believe there is some way.

Comment: Maybe you find something in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033836/adding-console-log-to-every-function-automatically

Comment: If you're willing to use backported features from ESNext, you can always use [decorators](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/). Babel has a plugin for [this](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators).

Comment: Check out AOP (aspect-oriented programming), it can solve such problems. An implementetion in javascript: https://blog.bitsrc.io/aspect-oriented-programming-in-javascript-c4cb43f6bfcc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could rewrite all the methods of the classes prototype by iterating over all own property names (`Object.keys` or `for..in` would not work here as class methods are not enumerable) and then replacing the original methods by a new method that calls the original method but also calls the middleware. Through that the classes behaviour doesnt change, but the middleware gets called.

```js
 class MyClass {
    a() { console.log("a"); }
 }

 function middleware() { 
    console.log("works");
 }

 for(const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(MyClass.prototype)) {
     const old = MyClass.prototype[key];
     MyClass.prototype[key] = function(...args) {
       middleware(...args);
       old.call(this, ...args);
     };
 }

 (new MyClass).a();
```

Comment: totally depends on the use case , here you cant write component specfic things , or cant event bind the context .

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in order to trap every property access on the instance, and wrap functions.

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    const handler = {
      get: function (obj, prop) {
        return typeof obj[prop] !== "function"
          ? obj[prop]
          : function (...args) {
              obj.middleware(prop);
              obj[prop].apply(obj, args);
            };
      },
    };
    return new Proxy(this, handler);
  }

  middleware(prop) {
    console.log(`Executing function ${prop}`);
  }

  a() {}

  b() {}

  c() {}
}

const obj = new MyClass();

obj.a();
obj.b();
obj.c();
```

Answer (score -3):

what you can is instead of calling directly function a,b,c , you can call middleware and pass the function in the parameter , middleware will call it at last.

```
function middleware(targetFunction) {
    console.log('call me before');
    targetFunction();
}
```

Comment: Sure, yes, its possible.

Comment: This may cause problems. The functions passed to `middleware` will lose their context, in other words, the `this` inside them will most likely be something other than the instance.

Comment: depends how/form where you call the function , you can always bind it