# Join first two elements and create new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

After playing around with the `join()` and `slice()` functions for hours, I have just found that you can't use either function on complex arrays. So I've come to get some help here.

I'm trying to get my data below:

```
 var data = [
            ["North", "Tennis",37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
            ["East", "Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
            ["South", "Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
            ["West", "Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
            ["North East", "Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
            ["North West", "Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
        ];
```

To look like this (output):

```
var result = [
    ["North: Tennis", 37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
    ["East: Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
    ["South: Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
    ["West: Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
    ["North East: Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
    ["North West: Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you wants to convert your array into an object?

Comment: @MohammadUsman Not at all, the rest of my code will use an array. I just want to reformat it and by appending a colon just after the first index and remove the comma

Comment: So you want to get one string as output? Or an array of strings? Or an array of arrays where the first two elements get joined by `:` ? Or ... ?

Comment: An array of arrays where the first to elements are joined by `:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you want to turn one array into another array, it makes sense to `.map` the original array to another array by taking the first two elements of each subarray and concatenating them together, then building a new subarray by adding the rest of the elements (which we get with the rest parameter during the array destructuring) to a new array that contains the joined string.

```js
let data = [
  ["North", "Tennis",37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
  ["East", "Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
  ["South", "Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
  ["West", "Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
  ["North East", "Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
  ["North West", "Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
];

let result = data.map(([s1, s2, ...rest]) => [`${s1}: ${s2}`, ...rest]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**References:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)
- [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

I'd write your code.

```js
var data = [
  ["North", "Tennis", 37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
  ["East", "Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
  ["South", "Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
  ["West", "Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
  ["North East", "Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
  ["North West", "Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
];

// Final resulting array is created by concatenating the first and
// second index elements of each inner array of data. The rest data
// is being copied as it is using slice and spread operator.
const result = data.reduce(
  (mem, cur) => [...mem, [`${cur[0]}: ${cur[1]}`, ...cur.slice(2)]],
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: IMO: `reduce` overcomplicates things here, why not just `map` ? Why I downvoted: *I'd write your code.* is *not* a description of whats going on.

Comment: @JonasWilms Here is nothing to explain, each line is pretty self explnatory. Want me to explain each line? Only one method I used `.reduce` here. What should I explain about the `reduce`?

Comment: @JonasWilms What explanation you got from `You can use .map() and some array destructuring`... from here? Nothing.. But I am ok with this line..

Comment: It doesnt matter if the explanation is good or not, but he at least tried to explain whats going on. You just dumped code. (Removed my downvote due to the edit)

Comment: @JonasWilms That is not an explation.. It was mentioned like that for to make happy people like you.. which I skip. I don't bother people who argues for no reasons..

Comment: @JonasWilms What kind of answer [is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903116/run-a-function-every-time-any-function-in-class-is-called-using-js/51903233#51903233) mate ? Did you put any effort here to explain instead of writing the code itself? Make yourself first presentable, then comment on others.. That said, I will stop commenting here.. I just try to ignore crap..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for the following output. I've used JavaScript's `.map()` function to restructure the data slightly. [More information on .map here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var data = [
  ["North", "Tennis", 37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
  ["East", "Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
  ["South", "Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
  ["West", "Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
  ["North East", "Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
  ["North West", "Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
];

const formattedData = data.map(row => {

  return [
    [row[0] + ': ' + row[1]],
    row[2],
    row[3],
    row[4],
    row[5],
    row[6],
    row[7]
  ];
});

console.log(formattedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` method. It takes a callback which is executed for every element. It then returns a **new** array with the new data in each index. For example:

```js
var data = [
            ["North", "Tennis",37, 25, 11, 9, 42, 13],
            ["East", "Football", 41, 2, 3, 26, 47, 21],
            ["South", "Rugby", 7, 22, 35, 45, 11, 46],
            ["West", "Rugby", 30, 21, 44, 23, 4, 47],
            ["North East", "Football", 35, 27, 12, 39, 34, 13],
            ["North West", "Football", 23, 4, 41, 35, 9, 47]
        ];
        
        
newData = data.map((el, i, arr) => {
  el[0] = `${el[0]}: ${el[1]}`   // reassinging el[0]
  el.splice(1, 1);               // removing 2 array element
 });
```