# How to find out what function is being called from a certain file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am not really sure if this is the right place to ask this question. But I am working with a code base that I am very new to and I want to see what functions are being called from a certain file using Chrome dev tools.

Comment: There are some ideas here by using your own code (not Chrome web dev tools) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034657/10634638

Answer (score 1):

If you're running the project locally, you might be able to check out the `Sources` tab in devtools. If your project is set up propery to do so (i.e. not minified or something) you can usually navigate to the file that has the functions you want to check out. From there you can actually put break points on each function and step through them, or just see what values they're receiving. This is all assuming it's a web based project done in jquery, or react, or just plain old javascript, and not a node.js project or something similar.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah of course you can always do that. However what if the file 4,000 lines of (I know not a good practice but it is what it is).

Comment: Is it just one file? If you break on a known space, you can step over and into functions to see what they're being called with/what they're calling. I'm not personally sure of any other way to just see what functions are being called? edit: Capitalization