# Logging performance.now() in console

Tags: javascript, logging, console, dom-events

Is it possible to log calling `performance.now()` in Javascript in console? 
I could not get result in console and I think `performance.now()` is not an event that can be observable in console as an event.

My code:

```
function myFunction() { Hi(); } function Hi() { performance.now(); }
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: function myFunction() {

  Hi();
}

function Hi() {
  performance.now();
}

Comment: Are you using `console.log()`?

Comment: at first I used monitorEvents() and then the code in the first answer in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033836/adding-console-log-to-every-function-automatically

Comment: Doesn't that complicate your actual question?

Comment: If I want to say simple, the number of calling of performance.now() in a web page is important for my purpose, so I want to log them and by a variable count them. My question is that if I can monitor this event or not

Comment: You mean that I type console.log(performance.now()) in the console?